# How do I create a variable name for an object from a list of strings in Python

Tags: python, list, object

I have a list of 16 different strings that I want to become the names of different objects.

For example

```
class Pieces:
    def __init__(self, name, file_name, r, c, color, side):
        self.name = name
        self.file_name = file_name
        self.r = r
        self.c = c
        self.pos = (r, c)
        self.color = color
        self.side = side
```

I have a dictionary that shares the keys with the list and has the values needed to create the object, however when I use a simple for loop its not stored.

```
for item in list_of_pieces:
    item = Pieces(*Pieces_dict[item])
```

Any way to have it save the string that is "item" and have it stay as an object callable for future use.

Comment: This can be done with a simple list comprehension: `pieces = [Pieces(*value) for value in Pieces_dict.values()]`

Comment: Or a `dict` comprehension: `pieces = {item: Pieces(*value) for item, value in Pieces_dict.items()}`.

Comment: I don't want them in the same object or list but want the "item" string itself to be the objects callable name. To be able to say item.function(function defined in the class)

Comment: Don't do that. How would you *end up using the resulting variables*?

Comment: I would use it as a typical object.

Comment: Just want to be able to iterate through a list and asssign them to be the varible name of the object